# MySQL Query: GROUP BY without loosing rows in result

Tags: mysql

I have written a MySQL query, but I am not quite happy with the output.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  f.id,
  s.time,
  f.name,
  f.value
FROM 
  entries s,
  entry_details f 
WHERE
  f.id = s.id AND (f.name = 'fruit' OR f.name = 'vegetable');
```

And produces this result:

```
id | time       | name      | value
---|------------|-----------|--------
4  | 2016-01-14 | fruit     | banana
4  | 2016-01-14 | vegetable | carrot
5  | 2016-01-14 | fruit     | apple
5  | 2016-01-14 | vegetable | corn
```

While all info required is in there, I was wondering if there is a way get the all results for `f.id` into one row?

Using `GROUP BY f.id` I achieved what I wanted, but then the `vegetable` rows disappears.

Is this even possible with MySQL alone?

Comment: what would you like the result to be?

Comment: Can you give us the table structures you are working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you need combine(aggregate) rest columns:

```
SELECT 
  f.id,
  MAX(s.time) AS `time`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(f.name) AS `name`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(f.value) AS `value`
FROM  entries s
JOIN entry_details f 
  ON f.id = s.id 
WHERE f.name IN('fruit', 'vegetable')
GROUP BY f.id;
```

Avoid using old comma join syntax, use newer `JOIN` instead.

Output:

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ id ║    time    ║       name      ║     value      ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╣
║  4 ║ 2016-01-14 ║ fruit,vegetable ║ banana, carrot ║
║  5 ║ 2016-01-14 ║ fruit,vegetable ║ apple, corn    ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: Avoid using unspecified join type, use explicit `inner/left/right join`.

Comment: @weirdan comma separated join is `INNER JOIN` and `INNER` is not mandatory. If you want to be super specific, you should write: use explicit`INNER/LEFT OUTER/RIGHT OUTER JOIN`